# Как запихнуть аудио-файли в программу С++?

Tags: c++

Есть программа, которая использует аудио-файли(они размещены в папке). Бывает случаи, когда пользователь может их удалить. Как скрыть эти файлы?

Comment: Как эти файлы используются?

Comment: они сохраняют звук который проигриваеться в программе

Comment: Ну это понятно. Как именно вы их проигрываете? Какой-то библиотекой?

Comment: PlaySound(TEXT("sound//win.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);

Comment: Запихнуть файл в "ресурсы". Вот тут немного про это есть: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd743680(v=vs.85)

Comment: А ещё бывают случаи, когда пользователи диск форматируют, пальцы в розетку суют и многие другие нехорошие вещи делают. Ну и чёрт с ними!